# how to best design a wrapper for an access database using c# 3.0?

Tags: database, .net-3.5, console, wrapper

i have only very limited exposure with .net 1.1 and a bit of 2.0, so i'm actually pretty excited and confused with the many changes that they have in .net 3.5. so i have this access database but we don't want the other programs from calling into this database directly. so i'm writing a wrapper exe which will contains functions which can be call by the other program to return data (ala web service style).

so for now i have manage to create a console app, encrypted the connection string and pull some data from the database.

1. how do i make it so that the other programs can call this exe's function?
2. how do i return the appropriate data to the calling program?
3. and is there's something wrong or a
   better design for my case?

i would love to learn from any dot net guys here :)
thanks.

Comment: +1 Nice Question, you just need to layout your problem a little easier. Maybe be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use existing Data Access Layer technology to encapsulate the call to Access database?

I used Strongly typed datasets for Microsoft Access database before. And you can use NHibernate, too.

Comment: +1. Good suggestion, but maybe overkill for a simple solution.

Comment: yea, hopefully best design doesnt' means complicated, as i just need this simple wrapper to allow the calling program to call certain functions, get data and get out! :)